# Error when I try to build framework file with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, compilation

Command:

```
C:\Users\Vince\Desktop\cordova-android\framework>ant jar
```

Build:

```
-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at D:\softs\android-SDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Cordova
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for Cordova...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.3
[gettarget] API level:        18
     [echo] ----------
```

**ERROR:**

```
    [javac]   symbol:   method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)
    [javac]   location: class CordovaWebView
    [javac] C:\Users\Vince\Desktop\cordova-android\framework\src\org\apache\co
rdova\IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.
VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && "content".equals(uri.getScheme());
    [javac]
             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] Note: C:\Users\Viince\Desktop\cordova-android\framework\src\org\apa
che\cordova\CordovaWebView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 4 errors

BUILD FAILED
D:\softs\android-SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while
 executing this line:
D:\softs\android-SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler e
rror output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

Any advice to take down this error would be great! thanks to all people who will put an answer. I have Android SDK build-tools 20.

Comment: Error fix! Thanks to Jul13nT to have looked at my question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this exact error by opening the project in Eclipse and then right clicking on the CordovaLib Project then properties, and then under 'Android' ensuring API version 19 was selected.

This matched what i had selected in My App project and what is entered below.

Then i ran the commands as described here:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md

```
android update project -p platforms/android/

cd platforms/android/

ant clean

cd FacebookLib

ant clean

open -e AndroidManifest.xml 

// change your minSdkVersion and your targetSdkVersion to your environment settings for me it was:
// <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

ant release

cd ../../..

cordova build android
```